# Is it required to use O_TRUNC and O_APPEND together?

Tags: linux, posix, fcntl

I was going through the book `The Linux Programming Interface`. On page 73 in Chapter 4,
it is written:

`fd = open("w.log", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);`

I read that `O_TRUC` flag is used to truncate the file length to zero that destroys any existing data in the file.

`O_APPEND` flag is used to append data to the end of the file.

The kernel records a `file offset`, sometimes also called the `read-write offset or pointer`. This is the location in the file at which the next `read()` or `write()` will commence.

I am confused that if the file is truncated and the kernel does the subsequent writing at the end of the file, why is the append flag is needed to explicitly tell to append at the end of the file?

Without the append flag (if the file is truncated), the kernel writes at the end of the file for the subsequent `write()` function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `O_APPEND` flag is used to append data to the end of the file.

That's true, but incomplete enough to be potentially misleading.  And I suspect that you are in fact confused in that regard.

> The kernel records a file offset, sometimes also called the read-write offset or pointer. This is the location in the file at which the next `read()` or `write()` will commence.

That's also incomplete.  There is a file offset associated with at least each seekable file.  That is the position where the next `read()` will commence.  It is where the next `write()` will commence *if the file is not open in append mode*, but in append mode *every* write happens at the end of the file, as if it were repositioned with `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` before each one. In that case, then, the current file offset might not be the position where the next `write()` will commence.

> I am confused that if the file is truncated and the the kernel does the subsequent writing at the end of the file why the append flag is needed to explicitly tell to append at the end of the file ?

It is not needed to cause the *first* write (by any process) after truncation to occur at the end of the file because immediately after the file has been truncated there isn't any other position.

> With out the append flag (if the file is truncated), the kernel writes at the end of the file for the subsequent write() function call.

It is not needed for subsequent writes either, *as long as the file is not repositioned or externally modified*.  Otherwise, the location of the next write depends on whether the file is open in append mode or not.

In practice, it is not necessarily the case that every combination of flags is useful, but the combination of `O_TRUNC` and `O_APPEND` has observably different effect than does either flag without the other, and the combination is useful in certain situations.

Answer (score 2):

`O_APPEND` rarely makes sense with `O_TRUNC`.  I think no combination of the C `fopen` modes  will produce that combination (on POSIX systems, where this is relevant).

`O_APPEND` ensures that every write is done at the end of the file, automatically, regardless of the write position. In particular, this means that if multiple processes are writing to the file, they do not stomp over each other's writes.

> note that POSIX does not require the atomic behavior of `O_APPEND`. It requires that an automatic seek takes place to the (current) end of the file before the write, but it doesn't require that position to still be the end of of the file when the write occurs. Even on implementations which feature atomic `O_APPEND`, it might not work for all file systems. The Linux man page on `open` cautions that `O_APPEND` doesn't work atomically on NFS.

Now, if every process uses `O_TRUNC` when opening the file, it will be clobbering everything that every other process wrote. That conflicts with the idea that the processes shouldn't be clobbering each other's writes, for which `O_APPEND` was specified.

`O_APPEND` is not required for appending to a file by a single process which is understood to be the only writer. It is possible to just seek to the end and then start writing new data. Sometimes `O_APPEND` is used in the exclusive case anyway simply because it's a programming shortcut. We don't have to bother making an extra call to position to the end of the file. Compare:

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "a");
// check f and start writing
```

versus:

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
// check f
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END); // go to the end, also check this for errors
// start writing
```

We can think about the idea that we have a group of processes using `O_APPEND` to a file, such that the first one also performs `O_TRUNC` to truncate it first. But it seems awkward to program this; it's not easy for a process to tell whether it is the first one to be opening the file.

If such a situation is required on, say, boot-up, where the old file from before the boot is irrelevant for some reason, just have a boot-time action (script or whatever) remove the old file before these multiple processes are started. Each one then uses `O_CREAT` to create the file if necessary (in case it is the first process) but without `O_TRUNC` (in case they are not the first process), and with `O_APPEND` to do the atomic (if available) appending thing.

Answer (score 0):

The two are entirely independent. The file is simply opened with `O_APPEND` because it's a log file.

The author wants concurrent messages to concatenate instead of overwrite each other (e.g. if the program forks), and if an admin or log rotation tool truncates the file then new messages should start being written at line #1 instead of at line #1000000 where the last log entry was written. This would not happen without O_APPEND.